# View SQL Server 2016 Login Audits

Tags: sql-server, audit

I have Login Audits for both failed and successful. How do i view the actual logs? Where are they located?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/configure-login-auditing-sql-server-management-studio

Is there a way to ignore service accounts?

Comment: Please look at [View a SQL Server Audit Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/view-a-sql-server-audit-log).

Comment: Ok I see that but it doesnt tell me users who failed/successfully connected to a DB? Its only for users Logging into the Server itself?

Comment: Does my answer below give you what you need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would change the setting in properties to `None` and set up a security audit where you have better control on what you want to audit, for how long you want to retain the result and exclude account you do not want to audit.

[image]

Create a Server Audit Specification for Failed login only.  You can add other `audit action type` as you need.

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE SERVER AUDIT SPECIFICATION [Audit_Spec_FaileLogin]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [FailedLogin]
ADD (FAILED_LOGIN_GROUP)
WITH (STATE = ON)
GO
```

This script will create a new login fail audit. Replace filepath, maxsize, max_files.  To exclude service account replace the value where I have `ServiceAccount` in the script.

```
USE [master]
GO


CREATE SERVER AUDIT [FailedLogin]
TO FILE 
(   FILEPATH = N'C:\'
    ,MAXSIZE = 64 MB
    ,MAX_FILES = 50
    ,RESERVE_DISK_SPACE = OFF
)
WITH
(   QUEUE_DELAY = 1000
    ,ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE

)
WHERE ([server_principal_name]<>'ServiceAccount')
ALTER SERVER AUDIT [FailedLogin] WITH (STATE = ON)
GO
```

Use this process as documented in below link to read the audit file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-get-audit-file-transact-sql

Two more resource to learn about security audit.

1. [SQL Server Security Audit Basics](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/sql-server-security-audit-basics/) by Feodor Georgiev
2. [SQL Server Audit (Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine)

Comment: ok but ideally I guess what I am looking for is to see what users connected to a specific database on in the instance. I guess I didnt write my question clearly.

Comment: Check this document and if it not listed here you might have to roll out your own Extended event trace. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-action-groups-and-actions

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the option found in the Server Properties -> Security window (screenshot below), you can view the logs captured by this in the SQL Server ERRORLOGs, which are found under the Management -> SQL Server Logs folder.

If you want to filter your service accounts out of this, you'll ned to setup a [SQL Server Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine) as you are unable to customize the basic Security auditing to anything other than None, Failed, Successful, or both Failed and Successful.  If you are interested in setting up an Audit, be sure your instance is patched to SP1 CU1 or later if you're not using Enterprise edition as this feature was exclusive to Enterprise prior to this patch.  Here's a [blog post](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-server-login-auditing.aspx) by Eralper Yilmaz that runs through how to set one of these up.

**The Option:**
 [image]

**The Log File Viewer Window and some examples of what you'll see:**
[image]

Comment: Ok great but it doesnt show me what database I am connecting to? just says this user connected using windows auth.

Comment: @Geo.Dude just expand the window... state 38 = failed to open database. the name of the database is on the trailing part of the message like 'Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database '**foo**'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]'

Comment: I dont see the database name: Message
Login succeeded for user 'Domain\username'. Connection made using Windows authentication. [CLIENT: IPADDRESS]